# Error sending automated email

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a shared workbook which has a column that uses a data validation list. If `YES` is selected I'd like it to send an email to a certain department to prompt them to look at the workbook.

I've gotten this far

```
Sub SendMail()
    If Range("G10:G250") = "YES" Then
            With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").createitem(0)
                .To = "p***.h***@****.com"
                .Subject = "Update from Facility Manager"
                .Body = "Hi Property Services, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " Please follow the link to see update on Facilty Management Tracker"
                .Send
            End With
    End If
End Sub
```

but I keep getting a `type mismatch` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important, when asking about errors, to indicate where exactly the error happens. Place a breakpoint in the gutter of the code pane at the beginning of your code and step a line at the time with <kbd>F8</kbd>.

In your code the error "type mismatch" occurs on the line

```
If Range("G10:G250") = "YES" Then
```

A range that spans more than one cell can not have a string value. It is unclear if your intention is to traverse all cells in the range and send one mail if one or more cells indicate "YES". The following modified code of yours looks for a "YES" in the range, and if found, sets a boolean and stops looking further. Then if the boolean is set, prepares and sends the email.

```
Private Sub SendMail()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim y As Boolean

    'If Range("G10:G250").Value = "YES" Then
    y = False
    For Each cell In Range("G10:G250")
        If cell.Value = "YES" Then
            y = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If y Then
        With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").createitem(0)
            .To = "p***.h***@****.com"
            .Subject = "Update from Facility Manager"
            .Body = "Hi Property Services, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " Please follow the link to see update on Facilty Management Tracker"
            .Send  'during debugging you can use .Display instead (to avoid filling someones mailbox)
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked, thanks Tom :) any idea's how to force it to run automatically? Up to now it only works if I open the code and force it?

Comment: @PHope Automatically, but triggered by what? Perhaps you can use `Worksheet_Change` event. [Doc on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) *Occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link* . Here on SuperUser are hundreds of posts about this event, just enter it in the search box.

Comment: thank you for your reply. So, I have the macro set up (with your previous help), which works perfectly however I have to force the run. I would like it to send the email if, when saved, any cell in Column G has been changed to "YES"

Comment: Your original question was about the `type mismatch error`, which I already answered. I also already answered in comments, in general terms, an additional question about how to automate your task and how to find additional examples. Stack Exchange sites like SuperUser are based on the principle of "one question - one answer". You are welcome to ask more questions as new posts, they are free !:) Please spend some time reading the articles in [the help center](https://superuser.com/help) including [someone-answers](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)